# Replace 500GB raid1 with 120GB raid1 with mdadm

Tags: mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I have a home server with two mirrored (soft raid1 with mdadm) 500GB HDD that contain the operating system. I would like to replace both the drives with two 120GB SSD mirrored in raid1 the same way. The two current 500GB HDD have both LUKS on LVM. Note that the current 500GB array has very low disk usage (<10GB).

What is the safest (in terms of data loss prevention) way to replace the current raid1?

I have checked some guides and it is possible to resize both LUKS on LVM and mdadm raid1 arrays, however it is considered quite unsafe. Therefore, I am taking into consideration creating a completely new array with the two 120GB SSD - but I'm not sure on how to transfer safely the data from the old array to the new array (maybe create an image of the current array, then shrink it and write it to the new array?)

Comment: Do it the oldfashioned way (copy files e.g. `rsync -a`) unless you have strong reasons not to...

Comment: You could remove one working disk, then add half of your new pair and create that as a failed raid. Mount both,  copy the data. Then remove the old disk and build out the new array to have both its devices

Comment: @roaima I cannot add a smaller hard disk to an existing array